# VSCode where are git remotes listed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can find this information using GitLens extension and by using the command line, but using the standard VSCode Git menu/sidebar, how do you find out the remotes attached to the current folder? It doesn't seem to want to tell me this anywhere obvious. I've tried hovering, using the '...', clicking the status bar, etc...

thanks.

[image]

Comment: go to the repo directory on the command line and type `git remote --verbose`

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I even said it :)
I was more after whether vscode had this built in.

Comment: VSC only supports a very limited command subset of git. This is something you need to do daily??? Almost nobody uses multiple remotes.

Comment: Great question.  There should be some way of displaying the output of "git remote -v" within the source code tab, or on the info bar at the bottom.
+1 for "GitLens"

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be anything to *only* print the remotes, but digging around in [`commands.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/git/src/commands.ts), I found this sequence that may suffice.

First, use the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) to run "Git: Pull From..." (internally known as `command.pullFrom`):

[image: Screenshot: Command Palette, Git Pull from...]

With multiple folders open, this will prompt for which repo to query:

[image: Screenshot: Choose a repository]

It appears that the initially selected repo is always the one containing the active text editor, so you can just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> immediately.  If only one folder is open, that step is skipped.

This displays the "Pick a remote" choice:

[image: Screenshot: Pick a remote]

This lets you see your remotes, along with their URLs, which is what I think you wanted to see.

Just hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel out so you don't actually pull anything.